# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I am new to programming and while running some new code in eclipse, I came across this error and am completely lost.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab6
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Fill in the body according to the following comments
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in); 
        // Input file name
        String FileName=getFileName(in);
        // Input number of students
        int numOfStudents = FileIOHelper.getNumberOfStudents(FileName);
        Student students[] = getStudents(numOfStudents); 
        // Input all student records and create Student array and
        // integer array for total scores
        int[]totalScores = new int[students.length];
        for(int i=0; i< students.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=1; j<4; j++)
            {
                totalScores[i]= totalScores[i]+students[i].getScore(j);
            }
        }
        // Compute total scores and find students with lowest and
        // highest total score
        int i;
        int maxIndex =0;
        int minIndex =0;
        for(i=0; i<students.length; i++);
        {
            if(totalScores[i]>=totalScores[maxIndex])
            {
                maxIndex=i;
            }
            else if(totalScores[i]<=totalScores[minIndex])
            {
                minIndex=i;
            }
        }
```

problem seems to be in the line **if(totalScores[i]>=totalScores[maxIndex])**

Comment: The first few lines of the stack trace (which starts with your ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) are critical.

Comment: Another error in your code is the ; after the for().

Answer (score 5):

You have a `;` after your last `for`, so after the `for` executes with no additional commands in each step, the variable `i` will have the value `students.length` which is outside the bounds of the array. Then the `{ ... }` block following the for is executed once with that final value of `i`, causing the exception.

Remove that `;` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

problem in this lines

int[]totalScores = new int[students.length];

for(int i=0; i< students.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=1; j<4; j++)
            {
                totalScores[i]= totalScores[i]+students[i].getScore(j);
            }
        }

you allocated students.length size for the totalscore.. but u are using 4*students.length.. so arrayindex out of bounds occured. use this

int[]totalScores = new int[4*students.length];

thanks
arefin

Comment: that's not the problem, he never accesses anything like `totalScores[i*j]`, just `totalScores[i]` (and `students[i]`), so the size is right.